# Managed metadata language in the Document Information Panel

Tags: office-integration, managed-metadata, language

If a document uses a Managed Metadata field, is there a way to make the term set browser in Word 2010's Document Information Panel display the term sets in a language other than the default language of the Managed Metadata Service?  For instance, even if the document comes from a document library on a site created in French and opened with Word 2010 whose default display language is French, if the default language of the Managed Metadata Service is English, the Document Information Panel will display metadata in English.  If you change the default language of the Managed Metadata Service, Word 2010 will follow the new default.

Is there a less drastic way to select this language within the DIP?

Comment: As far as I can test this, the answer is no. I have tried by checking the cache and playing with local language and remote language options and I cannot find a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

According to Nick Hobbs, page 10 in the reference below, Managed Meta Data are not "compatible" with the Document Information Panel.

Clearly, there are some obvious stengths in linguistic management within metadata mamagement, and it would be even stronger, if document infromation panel would comprehend this feature.

However, a possible scenario could be to associate the desired field programatically to the regional variations of the selected terms... maybe another too drastic approach?

Reference:
http://www.slideshare.net/nick_hobbs/share-point-2010-managed-metadata#btnNext

Answer (score 0):

If Word is installed in French, the DIP will display French metadata choices